# How do i set a public URL when using EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an instance setup for a test site using `Amazon Web Services` listed under `EC2`.

I then setup an `Elastic IP` which as i understand is a static IP.

Once logged into this instance of Windows Server i setup a site in `IIS` which runs locally.

I have set all the bindings in IIS but struggling to figure out how i assign a public name to this instance so i can view the site in an external browser? I tried entering the IP but that doesnt open anything, not even the standard IIS page?

Comment: What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the EC2 instance? Is it permitting inbound access on port 80/443?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your firewall if you have opened the port 80 or whatever the IIS is bonded with
and also check your security group of the EC2 instance and open the port 80 to the world